# Proof verification: every injection $A \to A$ is surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that if $A$ is a finite set, then every injection $f: A \to A$ is surjective. Here is my attempt.

> Let $f: A \to A$ be an injection. For each $a \in A$, let $N(a)$ denote the cardinality of the collection $\{f^{-1} (\{a\}\}$ of preimages for $a$ under $f$. Notice that, because $A$ is finite, $f^{-1} (\{a\})$ is finite for each $a$, so $N(a)$ is well-defined. As $f$ is injective, for each $a$, $N(a) \leq 1$; otherwise, for some $a \in A$, there exist distinct preimages $b,b' \in A$ such that $f(b) = a = f(b')$, contradicting injectivity of $f$. Furthermore, as the fibres of $f$ partition its domain, we have $\sum\limits_{a \in A} N(a) = |A|$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $f$ is not surjective. Then $A \setminus f(A) \neq \emptyset$, so there exists $t \in A \setminus f(A)$. Then $N(t) < 1$, i.e., $N(t) = 0$. We then have
> \begin{align*}
> \sum\limits_{a \in A} N(a) = \sum\limits_{a \in A \setminus \{t\}} N(a) + N(t) \leq \sum\limits_{a \in A \setminus \{t\}} 1 + N(t) = |A\setminus \{t\}| + 0 < |A|
> \end{align*}
> since $A \setminus \{t\}$ is a proper subset of $A$, contradicting surjectivity of $f$. Therefore, there exists no such $t$, and we have $A \setminus f(A) = \emptyset$, hence $A = f(A)$, so $f$ is surjective.

How does this look? I worry that my assertion in the final step is a leap of logic. Even though it seems obvious that $A \setminus \{t\}$ has cardinality strictly less than $A$, I think this is what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: Your approach is fine, though you might have to use induction on the cardinality of $A$ to address the concern you raised. Indeed, for an injection $g\colon A\to A\setminus\{t\}$ the restriction $A\setminus\{t\}\to A\setminus\{t\}$ is an injection which cannot be surjective (based on ideas you have used in your work already) and this would contradict a suitable induction hypothesis.